# Update Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-10.04

I keep getting this message when I logged into my server in AWS EC2 via ssh

I think this is called MOTD

```
43 packages can be updated.
22 updates are security updates.
```

but I have already done

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I have also restarted my instance.

Please advise.

Comment: Is your instance ephemeral or EBS backed?

Comment: EBS backed instance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another one of these "fine" Ubuntu-bugs... Check Ubuntu Bug #634387: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sysvinit/+bug/634387

I deleted the files "/etc/motd.tail" and "/etc/motd.tail.old" and did a logout / login to re-genereate a propper /etc/motd.

Answer (score 32):

This is coming from the MOTD (Message Of The Day). The MOTD is pieced together from the commands in `/etc/update-motd.d`. The specific message comes from running `/etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available`.

I have seen this happen on systems where after running `sudo apt-get update` and packages are kept back

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

The message can mean several things e.g. there may be dependency issues etc. there is more on this in the [APT HowTo](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-apt-get.en.html).

I have managed to stop the messages with

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
```

If that doesn't work then the link above does give advice on how to track down the problem packages.

Comment: This fixed the problem on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)

Answer (score 5):

I was seeing this same issue on Ubuntu 14.04

I edited `/etc/pam.d/sshd`

and changed this line
`session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic noupdate`

by removing the `noupdate`

now the banner displays correctly.

Comment: I think *this* answer is moving in the right direction for 14.04. On my own server (Ubuntu Server in a virtual machine), the motd changed after `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. In my case, that required a server restart, so I don't know whether the change to motd was little bit of a coincidence. I did *not* have to edit any of the files in /etc/pam.d, but I think I'd have first tried editing /etc/pam.d/login. That files has the same motd lines as sshd.

Comment: I've simply restarted after `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and the message was fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Run the following command:

```
sudo /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available --force
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer, but it turns out my expectations were incorrect, and the answer itself may be correct.  Unfortunately, serverfault has locked(!!) my downvote and I cannot undo it unless the answer is edited.  :-(

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 18.04 - Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After numerous failed attempts, the recipe that works for me is based on Kimi and Lex Miller:

```
$ sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
$ sudo /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available --force
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades

sudo dpkg-reconfigure --priority=low unattended-upgrades

sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow unattended-upgrades -f noninteractive -p critical
```

For more details:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates

Comment: You give a recipe, but you're not giving any explanation or justification.