# ubuntu server: SSH banner telling to update packages but nothing to update

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-10.04, apt, package-management

When I connect to my Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS server I get the following banner:

```
25 packages can be updated.
15 updates are security updates.
```

However if I run package upgrades/updates nothing comes up:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

After doing some research I found that issuing `apt-get dist-upgrade` could help but it makes no difference.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: see another solution at http://serverfault.com/questions/262751/updates-in-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-10-04-server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That banner you're talking about is called MOTD (Message Of The Day). It appears to be [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/766827/comments/3) which can be work-arounded by deleting the `/etc/motd.tail` file.