# Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 LTS: MOTD always displays the same packages to be updated

Tags: ubuntu, motd

Since yesterday I always get this message when I log in via SSH:

2 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

There's nothing to be updated running apt-get update and apt-get upgrade:

sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

(1 not upgraded: I can't find it)

I've followed these posts but to no avail:

[ubuntu server: SSH banner telling to update packages but nothing to update](https://serverfault.com/questions/270094/ubuntu-server-ssh-banner-telling-to-update-packages-but-nothing-to-update)

[Ubuntu tells me I have packages to upgrade when I don't](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36517/ubuntu-tells-me-i-have-packages-to-upgrade-when-i-dont)

Any hints/suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I get similar behavior when there is kernel updates.

Run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and you should get rid of this one package.

`dist-upgrade` Will install new kernel and such, it does not install a newer release of Ubuntu.